# Internal 500 Error with DateTime set in Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, asp.net-web-api

Hey I'm getting a weird internal 500 error. I narrowed it down to finding that the DateTime structure gives me this, but I'm having a hard time understanding why. So I am using asp.net web api and currently storing info as so.

```
 public void StoreFacebookInfo(string accessToken, IdentityUser user)
    {
            //Retrieve Facebook Mutual Friends
            dynamic myMutualFriends = fb.Get(curFbId + "?fields=context.fields(mutual_friends)");
            if (myMutualFriends.context.mutual_friends.data != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in myMutualFriends.context.mutual_friends.data)
                {
                    var f = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<mutualFriends>(item.ToString());
                    profileInfo.mutualFriendsList.Add(f);
                }
            }
            //Save all information retrieved from FB into a db
            profileInfo.externalId = myInfo.id;
            profileInfo.name = myInfo.name;
            profileInfo.firstName = firstname.first_name;
            profileInfo.lastName = lastname.last_name;
            profileInfo.link = link.link;
            profileInfo.gender = gender.gender;
            profileInfo.imageURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + myInfo.id + "/picture?type=large";
            profileInfo.locale = locale.locale;

            profileInfo.UserId = user.Id;
            db.UserInfoes.Add(profileInfo);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
 }
```

As you can see, everything looks fine. In my model, I have the following:

```
  public class UserInfo
{
    public UserInfo()
    {
        this.friendsList = new List<friends>();
        this.mutualFriendsList = new List<mutualFriends>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string externalId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string imageURL { get; set; }
    public string locale { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
    public string travellevel { get; set; }
    public DateTime birthdate { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public IdentityUser User { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public List<mutualFriends> mutualFriendsList { get; set; }
    public List<friends> friendsList { get; set; }
}
```

When I am using DateTime for the birthdate, when it gets to db.saveChanges(), the code runs into an internal 500 error. When I change this DateTime into string the code runs fine and I am able to save the information. This is strange to me because when I run it on another computer, it works completely fine with the DateTime and not changing it to string.

It'd be great if you could explain this error a bit. Thanks for any help.

Comment: you not saving date value in  StoreFacebookInfo function.Null value giving error

Comment: Doesn't DateTime have a preset value of {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}. Also why would this work on varying computers. I haven't changed anything regarding the dbs.

Comment: Did you try putting a `try...catch` around data saving logic and see stack trace/inner exception, what exactly the error you are getting?

Comment: @SivaGopal How would I do that please explain? specifically more on what to catch?

Comment: in StoreFacebookInfo function,assign default value to date

Comment: E.g profileInfo.birthdate = DateTime.Now()

Comment: E.g: `try{ db.SaveChanges();}catch(System.Exception ex){throw;}`. Put a break point on catch and check.

Comment: @MuhammadAtif Is there a way to have birthdate null because for local users, birthday would need to be filled. I would like for them to enter into an empty input rather than a prefilled date that is DateTime.Now? I tried updating database to allow null.

Comment: @JuliusDoan Try `DateTime?` which is nullable DateTime.

Comment: in UserInfo class declare datetime as DateTime?

Comment: Thanks guys for the very helpful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is the language culture of your client who is different of your server and which badly parse the DateTime (ie: dd/MM/yyyy vs MM/dd/yyyy).

Try to serialize and parse the DateTime in the same format.